# How to set session max inactive time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, session

I get the session MaxInactiveInterval time using the following query. I am developing web application using JSF Framework

```
var sessionMaxInactiveTime = ${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval};
```

I need to set **maxInactiveInterval**.
how to set maxInactiveInterval using JavaScript, JQuery, or to write Servlet.
But i want to control to  main template jsp Page.

Is available any links, notes or samples?

Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In doPost or doGet method in your servlet, first get Session object and call setMaxInactiveInterval() method on Session. 
You can similarly get session object & set max inactive interval (by calling setMaxInactiveInterval() method) from your JSP page.

Below is servlet example:

```
    // Get the current session object, create one if necessary
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    // Set the timeout
    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(2*60*60);  // two hours
```

You can find similar and more examples related to Servlet and sessions here :http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/ServletSessionMaxInactiveInterval.htm